# Efficient way to capture "variations" or "combinations" ore "aliases" for switch-case argument(s) in PHP

Tags: php

I am pretty sure this challenge has been solved by someone already but even searching with different words, I could not find a solution for this problem:

I try to give users the possibility to run certain functions of a class based on an argument like

service_class::do_this( "selection-argument" );

but the user shall be able to use "clear words" as well as "aliases" and even "well known" abbreviations or synonyms.

I use switch-case construction to call the "real" function.

Example: To get the contens of a folder, The user can use "getdir", "dir", "Directory", "getfolder", "getcontent", "content", "d-cont" and a number of more other "matching words" to start the function(s) underlaying and getting back the very same result.

Capture-ing lowercase/uppercase is simple. What I search for is an efficient way to capture all possible "variations" - that are, of course different number of variations for different functions called.

At the moment I use multiple "case "": lines after each other, but that makes the code quite long, and further I would like the user to be able to "enahnce" the recognition set for a certain function.

That's why I thought about "stripos" to determine first what "internal word" to use and only then run into the switch-case construction.

Anyone had that issue and can direct me to a "good and efficient" solution?

Seems that Stck-exchange itself had a similar challenge (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/php/synonyms) ... maybe I can simply re-use the underlying code?

Thanks in advance and sorry if I overlooked a solution already posted.

Comment: Can you give me a use case where polymorphic names could be useful for calling a single method of a class?

Comment: Do you need deterministic or probabilistic match? That is, is set of accepted variants finite and known upfront?

Comment: @nice_dev: it's not actually "only" for methods but also kind of "synomisation" that also can be used for different languages. In my case, a string will be the input that will be sliced in parts and one of the parts will be rooms. Some people will use "salon", saloon", "living room", "Wohnzimmer" etc. for the very same room.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a database or array. Let's do the latter. So to determine whether an user wants to get a directory you would define an array like this:

```
$getDirVariants = ['getdir', 
                   'dir', 
                   'directory', 
                   'getfolder', 
                   'getcontent', 
                   'content', 
                   'd-cont'];
```

It is easy to add more of these arrays. To test the query word you would do:

```
$queryWord = strtolower($queryWord);
if (in_array($queryWord, $getDirVariants)) service_class::getDir(<arguments>);
elseif (in_array($queryWord, $deleteVariants)) service_class::delete(<arguments>);
```

You can easily add to the arrays or make it a 2D array to contain more commands. That array could also be placed in a database.

Especially when there are many commands, with many variants, a database will be the better solution, because you can find the query word with one database query.

There's a variation I can think of that will also simplify the code when there are many commands. You could use an associative array to find the command:

```
$commandVariants = ['getdir'     => 'getdir', 
                    'dir'        => 'getdir', 
                    'directory'  => 'getdir', 
                    'getfolder'  => 'getdir', 
                    'getcontent' => 'getdir', 
                    'content'    => 'getdir', 
                    'd-cont'     => 'getdir',
                    'delete'     => 'delete',
                    'del'        => 'delete',
                    'remove'     => 'delete',
                    'unlink'     => 'delete'];

$queryWord = strtolower($queryWord);
if (isset($commandVariants[$queryWord])) {
    $command = $commandVariants[$queryWord];
    service_class::$command(<arguments>);
}
else echo "I don't recognize that command.";
```

This uses a variable identifier.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I use the array-solution already but that (in my opinion) is a "lenghy" solution ... I hoped for somthing more "genius" ... please don't get me wrong guys!

I also used strpos( ).